# A-Frame super-hands move grabbed object

Tags: javascript, aframe, oculus, aframe-super-hands

I'm making an A-Frame project with the `aframe-super-hands-component`. To add a layer of control, I'm trying to make it so that the user can use a controller's joysticks to bring entities closer/farther away from the controller, similar to the Oculus Dash controls (https://youtu.be/sMjlM5vFSA0?t=1m55s).

However, when I try to update a model's position, as I do so when the model has been grabbed, it tries to move but gets stopped by the physics constraints set when `grab-start` is emitted.  Is there a way I can move a super-hands grabbed model or reset the constraint applied to the model?

Here's what it looks like when I try to update a grabbed box's position: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRck0.jpg

In terms of code, all I'm trying to do is update the position with `modelEl.object3D.position.sub(<direction vector>)` while it has the `grab-start` event bound to a controller.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly there is solution for this, if you look at the code for the physics example from the super-hands page here;

https://wmurphyrd.github.io/aframe-super-hands-component/examples/physics/

You will see that there is a component attached to the controllers as follows;

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('phase-shift', {
  init: function () {
    var el = this.el
    el.addEventListener('gripdown', function () {
      el.setAttribute('collision-filter', {collisionForces: true})
    })
    el.addEventListener('gripup', function () {
      el.setAttribute('collision-filter', {collisionForces: false})
    })
  }
})
```

This 'toggles' the physics constraint while grabbing which I think is what you are after.

Its hard to know what else you have going on but if you don't already you need to include the [`aframe-physics-extras`](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-physics-extras) component as well as super-hands and physics. to make that component work.

I hope that helps.

Comment: `collisionForces` just makes it so that the `static-body` attached to the controller will pass through or collide with the objects. Although I think that `collisionForces` and `aframe-physics-extras` is not relevant to my problem, I will go and investigate `aframe-physics-system`'s `constraint` component: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/blob/master/src/components/constraint.js